# Kendo Grid Column of type Decimal Losing Precision

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor, kendo-grid

I have bound some data to a Kendo grid and the problem I am running into is that the grid seems to only want to show two decimal places instead of 5 or 6 or whatever the real value is for the longitude and latitude columns.

Here is the code in my view:

```
<div class="gridPadding">    
    @(Html.Kendo().Grid((IEnumerable<DealerPortal.Models.DealerViewModel>)ViewData["DealerResults"])
                .Name("dealerSearchResults")
                .Columns(columns =>
                {
                    columns.Bound("DealerID");
                    columns.Bound("DealerName");
                    columns.Bound("TerminalID");
                    columns.Bound("Status");
                    columns.Bound("Address1");
                    columns.Bound("State");
                    columns.Bound("PhoneNumber");
                    columns.Bound("Email");
                    columns.Bound("Latitude");
                    columns.Bound("Longitude");
                    columns.Bound("EpayRetailerID");
                })
                .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource.Server().Model(model => model.Id(d => d.DealerID)))
                .Selectable(selectable => selectable.Mode(GridSelectionMode.Multiple))
                .Sortable()
            )
        </div>
```

Here is the DealerViewModel class:

```
public class DealerViewModel
{        
    public long DealerID { get; set; }
    public string DealerName { get; set; }
    public string Address1 { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public decimal? Latitude { get; set; }
    public decimal? Longitude { get; set; }
    public string EpayRetailerID { get; set; }
    public string TerminalID { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public char Status { get; set; }
}
```

When I step through the code I can see that `ViewData["DealerResults"]` holds the correct values for longitude and latitude, but the grid displayed on the webpage cuts it off after 2 decimal places. I only have the nullable decimal type to satisfy some error I was getting further upstream, but it doesn't seem like that should be the problem.

I also couldn't seem to find the way to format these values as sometimes they are negative values and the amount of decimal places changes.

I tried `columns.Bound("Latitude").Format("00.000");` which only made every value "00.000" and `columns.Bound("Latitude").Format("##.###");` which also made every value "##.###".

Any ideas? Thank you

Comment: Why not send through only formatted strings, instead of `decimal?`?

Comment: Because I'm too thick to think of that solution :/ Thank you for the idea!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try `columns.Bound("Latitude").Format("{0:n6}");` It will fill in all decimal places till the 6th place. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you - this worked. Do you have a link for this formatting documentation?

Comment: Check this link : http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/getting-started/framework/globalization/numberformatting